# Plot label distance to plot

Tags: plotting, labeling, style

Consider the two following similar expressions:

```
(* EXPRESSION 1 *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic,
 PlotLabel -> Style["PLOT LABEL", FontSize -> Medium, FontWeight -> Bold]]

(* EXPRESSION 2 *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
PlotLabel -> Style["PLOT LABEL", FontSize -> Medium, FontWeight -> Bold]]
```

the only difference between them being the `PlotRangePadding -> 0` option.

The first expression produces this result:

[image: Result of expression 1]

while the second one returns the following image:

[image: Result of expression 2]

As you can see, the distance of the text "PLOT LABEL" is different in each case.

I guess that the distance between the plot label and the plot does not take into account the plot padding. **Why is this happening? How can I avoid this behaviour? More precisely, how can I increase the distance between the plot label and the plot in case 1?**

In case it matters, I am using Mathematica 10.4.1 running on Windows 7.

Comment: The closest I get is to use `Labeled[plot, 
 Style["PLOT LABEL", {"Graphics", "GraphicsLabel", FontSize -> Medium,
    FontWeight -> Bold}], Top]`, but it is centered along the image center line, not the `Graphics` center line (subtle, but noticeable). The `Alignment` option could be used to further adjust it, but I don't have the time at the moment.

Comment: @rcollyer Thank you. Using `Labeled` is an option, of course. But I wonder whether or not it is possible to have a more consistent/coherent behaviour of the `PlotLabel` option.

Comment: `PlotLabel` is fairly low-level, i.e. it is handled by the renderer itself, so you have to get "creative". Here's something that works quite well: `PlotLabel -> 
 Pane[Style["PLOT LABEL", FontSize -> Medium, 
   FontWeight -> Bold], {Automatic, 20}, Alignment -> {Center, Top}]`. Let me know if that works for you, and I'll convert it to an answer.

Comment: @rcollyer It almost works for me. The result when NOT using `PlotRangePadding -> 0` is now acceptable but still different to that obtained when using `PlotRangePadding -> 0`. I have a pair of charts, one of each type, and I would like the corresponding labels to be the same distance from their respective chart. 

Anyway, you can post it as an answer, and we can wait and see.

Comment: I also encounter this problem, i find that it is affected by the major ticks, if the largest major ticks is not equal to the plot range, this will happen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `ImagePadding` and `Scaled`.  Also note that you should not need `PlotRange -> Automatic` as this is the default for the y-axis in `Plot`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLabel -> Style["PLOT LABEL", FontSize -> Medium, FontWeight -> Bold],
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Scaled[0.0025]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may try different values for the `Scaled` parameter to see which you prefer by using `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["PLOT LABEL", FontSize -> Medium, FontWeight -> Bold],
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Scaled[p]}}],
 {{p, .005}, 0, .1}
 ]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

A trick I have used is to put the label in an invisible frame and then monkey with the bottom frame margin. The following produces four plots using this trick, one  with no space and three with 4, 8, and 12 printer points, respectively, between the label and the plot frame.

```
Column[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotLabel ->
      Style[
        Framed["PLOT LABEL",
          ContentPadding -> False,
          FrameStyle -> Transparent,
          FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {#, 0}}],
      12, Bold]]& 
  /@ Subdivide[0, 12, 3]]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: An invisible frame - sounds like a `Pane` to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide a workaround for setting an arbitrary distance `dist` between the `PlotLabel` and the plot itself.

A way to introduce `dist` is to replace `"PLOT LABEL"` with

```
Framed["PLOT LABEL 1", FrameStyle -> White,
FrameMargins -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {dist, 0}}]
```

For example:

**a big distance (`dist=30`):**

```
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed["PLOT LABEL 1", FrameStyle -> White, 
     FrameMargins -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {30, 0}}], 
    FontSize -> Medium, FontWeight -> Bold]]
```

[image]

**a small distance (`dist=-2`):**

```
b = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed["PLOT LABEL 2", FrameStyle -> White, 
     FrameMargins -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {-2, 0}}], 
    FontSize -> Medium, FontWeight -> Bold]]
```

[image]

It's also decent with `GraphicsRow`:

```
c = GraphicsRow[{a, b}, ImageSize -> 1000, Spacings -> -40]
```

[image]

Maybe not very elegant, but it works.